# How to select a specific input file from directory to Mapreduce program

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am running a Mapreduce program and my input directory has multiple files. Let's say

- file1.txt
- file2.txt
- file3.txt

And I want to work with only file2.txt. How can I do that without deleting the remaining files from input directory?

Comment: How do you specify the input path currently? Simply add `/file2.txt` to the end of that path.

Comment: or `file2*` for all files starting with "file2" string in this path

Comment: @Jedi Thanks, actually I am pretty new to Hadoop !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the file name in code itself

Code:

```
 FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, "/inputfoldername/file2.txt");
```

Or you can do it on run time

Code:

```
 FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
```

Execution:

```
 hadoop jar Wordcount.jar Wordcount /inputfoldername/file2.txt /outputfoldername
```

For more details refer few Mapreduce POC available at https://ybhavesh.blogspot.com

**Hope this Helps!!!...**